# Multicondition redirect from first subpage of category to main page of category

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, parameters

We have URLs like this

1. site_com/category
2. site_com/category?page=1
3. site_com/category?page=2

The page for first and second URLs are the same. I need to create `301 redirect` from
`?page=1` to `/category`, besides "category" is a variable.

I've try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [a-z]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=1$

RewriteRule ^%1%2$ site_com/%1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=1$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^site/(.+)$ site/$1? [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: now i try RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1? [R=301,L] and it redirect to main, not for category((

Comment: Please, post sample input and your expected redirected URLs. You're question is quite vague without them.

Comment: http://site/anyurl?page=1 goto http://site/anyurl, but http://site/anyurl?page=2 without redirect

Comment: Is anyurl just a folder or a long path? My rule would redirect `domain.com/site/folder?page=1` to `domain.com/site/folder` What are you getting redirected to?

Comment: Is your htaccess in the root directory? That's important for the rules to work.

Comment: Yes,hta in root. Opencart CMS, I have 2 types of urls for caterogy. Main category have - http://site/gifts, child category http://site/gifts/passport-covers/ Both of categories have pages form 1 to N, i try to redirect 1 page to main url of category. All urls are not folders

Comment: Now, that explains the situation better. Please, try the updated rules and let me know.

Comment: Oh not working again. Think thats cms bug because simple redirectpermanent also not work for one exact category i used redirect 301 "full_ulr/cat?page=1" new_full_url? and /cat?page=1 /cat  with quotes and without